# Python, KivyMD get data from textfields

Tags: python, kivy

Since few weeks i'm using KivyMD and i fell in love of this Kivy Theme.
Here is my question : I'm making an multiple screen app using KivyMD and my first screen is a 'login screen'. And I want to add a function in my main class who gets the value of my 'username' textfield and my 'password' textfield. And if identifiers are correct it takes me to 'screen2'.

Here is my code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    scr_mngr = ObjectProperty(None)

    def change_screen(self, screen, *args):
        self.scr_mngr.current = screen


KV = """
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import ThemeManager kivymd.theming.ThemeManager
#:import MDNavigationDrawer kivymd.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import NavigationDrawerDivider 
kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerDivider
#:import NavigationDrawerToolbar 
kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerToolbar
#:import NavigationDrawerSubheader 
kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerSubheader
#:import MDCheckbox kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDCheckbox
#:import MDSwitch kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDSwitch
#:import MDList kivymd.list.MDList
#:import OneLineListItem kivymd.list.OneLineListItem
#:import TwoLineListItem kivymd.list.TwoLineListItem
#:import ThreeLineListItem kivymd.list.ThreeLineListItem
#:import OneLineAvatarListItem kivymd.list.OneLineAvatarListItem
#:import OneLineIconListItem kivymd.list.OneLineIconListItem
#:import OneLineAvatarIconListItem kivymd.list.OneLineAvatarIconListItem
#:import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:import MDSpinner kivymd.spinner.MDSpinner
#:import MDCard kivymd.card.MDCard
#:import MDSeparator kivymd.card.MDSeparator
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import colors kivymd.color_definitions.colors
#:import SmartTile kivymd.grid.SmartTile
#:import MDSlider kivymd.slider.MDSlider
#:import MDTabbedPanel kivymd.tabs.MDTabbedPanel
#:import MDTab kivymd.tabs.MDTab
#:import MDProgressBar kivymd.progressbar.MDProgressBar
#:import MDAccordion kivymd.accordion.MDAccordion
#:import MDAccordionItem kivymd.accordion.MDAccordionItem
#:import MDAccordionSubItem kivymd.accordion.MDAccordionSubItem
#:import MDThemePicker kivymd.theme_picker.MDThemePicker
#:import MDBottomNavigation kivymd.tabs.MDBottomNavigation
#:import MDBottomNavigationItem kivymd.tabs.MDBottomNavigationItem

#:import partial functools.partial

MyLayout:
    scr_mngr: scr_mngr
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ScreenManager:
        id: scr_mngr
        Screen:
            name: 'screen1'
            MDCard:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(520), dp(340)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    padding: dp(20)
                    spacing:20
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Connexion'
                        theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
                        font_style:"Title"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: dp(36)
                    MDSeparator:
                        height: dp(1)
                    MDTextField:
                        id: 'username'
                        hint_text: "Username "
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    MDTextField:
                        id: 'password'
                        hint_text: "Password "
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"

                    MDFlatButton:
                        text: "Connexion"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                        on_release: root.check_data_login()
        Screen:
            name: 'screen2'
            Toolbar:
                id: toolbar
                title: "Welcome ! "
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.97}
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                background_palette: 'DeepPurple'
                background_hue: 'A400'
                left_action_items: [['arrow-left', p 
                    partial(root.change_screen, 'screen1') ]]
                right_action_items: [['animation', lambda x: M 
                    MDThemePicker().open()]]

            MDLabel:
                font_style: 'Title'
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                text: "Data :"
                height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(3)
                halign: 'center'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}




"""


class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def check_data_login(self):
        username = self.username.text
        password= self.password.text

        print(username)
        print(password)

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

The solution is to use Kivy ObjectProperty to hook-up to the ids. Please refer to the example for details.

### kv File

Add the following id and ObjectProperties

1. Add `id: screen1`
2. Add ObjectProperty, `screen1: screen1`
3. id is not string. Remove quotes from `id: username` and `id: password`
4. Add ObjectProperty, `username: username`
5. Add ObjectProperty, `password: password`
6. Add `password: True` to TextInput so that the password is masked

#### Snippets - kv File

```
ScreenManager:
    id: scr_mngr
    screen1: screen1

    Screen:
        id: screen1
        name: 'screen1'
        username: username
        password: password

        MDCard:
            ...
                MDTextField:
                    id: username
                    hint_text: "Username "
                    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"

                MDTextField:
                    id: password
                    hint_text: "Password "
                    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    password: True
```

### Python File

1. Move `check_data_login()` method from `class MyApp()` into `class MyLayout()`
2. Replace `self.username.text` with `self.scr_mngr.screen1.username.text`
3. Replace `self.password.text` with `self.scr_mngr.screen1.password.text`
4. Added **if** statement to check username and password

#### Snippets - Python File

```
class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    scr_mngr = ObjectProperty(None)

    def check_data_login(self):
        username = self.scr_mngr.screen1.username.text
        password = self.scr_mngr.screen1.password.text

        print(username)
        print(password)

        if username == "KivyMD" and password == "kivy":
            self.change_screen("screen2")
```

## Kivy Documentation

[Syntax of a kv File](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file)

> If the widget doesn’t have a property with the given name, an
>   ObjectProperty will be automatically created and added to the widget.

[Referencing Widgets » ids](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

> **Warning**
>
> When assigning a value to id, remember that the value isn’t a string.
>   There are no quotes: good -> id: value, bad -> id: 'value'

[Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your python code](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

> it is generally regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty.
>   This creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more
>   explicit.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    scr_mngr = ObjectProperty(None)

    def check_data_login(self):
        username = self.scr_mngr.screen1.username.text
        password = self.scr_mngr.screen1.password.text

        print(username)
        print(password)

        if username == "KivyMD" and password == "kivy":
            self.change_screen("screen2")

    def change_screen(self, screen, *args):
        self.scr_mngr.current = screen


KV = """
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import ThemeManager kivymd.theming.ThemeManager
#:import MDNavigationDrawer kivymd.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import NavigationDrawerDivider kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerDivider
#:import NavigationDrawerToolbar kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerToolbar
#:import NavigationDrawerSubheader kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerSubheader
#:import MDCheckbox kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDCheckbox
#:import MDSwitch kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDSwitch
#:import MDList kivymd.list.MDList
#:import OneLineListItem kivymd.list.OneLineListItem
#:import TwoLineListItem kivymd.list.TwoLineListItem
#:import ThreeLineListItem kivymd.list.ThreeLineListItem
#:import OneLineAvatarListItem kivymd.list.OneLineAvatarListItem
#:import OneLineIconListItem kivymd.list.OneLineIconListItem
#:import OneLineAvatarIconListItem kivymd.list.OneLineAvatarIconListItem
#:import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:import MDSpinner kivymd.spinner.MDSpinner
#:import MDCard kivymd.card.MDCard
#:import MDSeparator kivymd.card.MDSeparator
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import colors kivymd.color_definitions.colors
#:import SmartTile kivymd.grid.SmartTile
#:import MDSlider kivymd.slider.MDSlider
#:import MDTabbedPanel kivymd.tabs.MDTabbedPanel
#:import MDTab kivymd.tabs.MDTab
#:import MDProgressBar kivymd.progressbar.MDProgressBar
#:import MDAccordion kivymd.accordion.MDAccordion
#:import MDAccordionItem kivymd.accordion.MDAccordionItem
#:import MDAccordionSubItem kivymd.accordion.MDAccordionSubItem
#:import MDThemePicker kivymd.theme_picker.MDThemePicker
#:import MDBottomNavigation kivymd.tabs.MDBottomNavigation
#:import MDBottomNavigationItem kivymd.tabs.MDBottomNavigationItem

#:import partial functools.partial

MyLayout:
    scr_mngr: scr_mngr
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ScreenManager:
        id: scr_mngr
        screen1: screen1

        Screen:
            id: screen1
            name: 'screen1'
            username: username
            password: password

            MDCard:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(520), dp(340)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    padding: dp(20)
                    spacing:20

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Connexion'
                        theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
                        font_style:"Title"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: dp(36)

                    MDSeparator:
                        height: dp(1)

                    MDTextField:
                        id: username
                        hint_text: "Username "
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"

                    MDTextField:
                        id: password
                        hint_text: "Password "
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        password: True

                    MDFlatButton:
                        text: "Connexion"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                        on_release: root.check_data_login()
        Screen:
            name: 'screen2'

            Toolbar:
                id: toolbar
                title: "Welcome ! "
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.97}
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                background_palette: 'DeepPurple'
                background_hue: 'A400'
                left_action_items: [['arrow-left', partial(root.change_screen, 'screen1') ]]
                right_action_items: [['animation', lambda x: MDThemePicker().open()]]

            MDLabel:
                font_style: 'Title'
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                text: "Data :"
                height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(3)
                halign: 'center'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}
"""


class MyApp(App):
    title = "Kivy MD Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - username & password entered]
[image: Img02 - Screen2 Displayed]

Comment: Wow ! Thank you very much ! You helped me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with a button.
Your kv file:

```
KV = """
Screen:
    
    
    MDLabel:
        id: direct
        text: 'Paste File Path: '
        color: [0.6,0.5,0.3,1,1]
                
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .55, "center_y": .7}

    MDTextField:
        id: getpath
        hint_text: "Include file name with its extension"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.7}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: "300dp"

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Check Text"
        color: "green"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .45}
        on_release: app.checkprint()

"""
```

And your main python script:

```
class OneApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Green'
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
    

        return self.screen

    
    def checkprint(self):
        value = self.screen.ids.getpath.text
        print("What you typed is: ", value)

OneApp().run()
```